# Subtract method in object if greater than zero

Tags: javascript, object, methods

I'm using a game object that has different getters and methods within it. One of the parameters of my assignment is that the "playerDies" method has to subtract 1 from the lives if it is greater than zero and it cannot go below 0 (so it can't be -1 which is what is happening now). This topic is fairly new to me so I'm not sure what I can do to execute the subtraction only when there is a specific value. I've tried using an if-else statement but that resulted in the code not working.
My code:

```
var game = {
    lives: 3,
    coins: 0,

    get points() {
        return this.coins * 10;
    },

    playerDies: function() {
            return this.lives -= 1;
    },

    newGame: function() {
         this.lives = 3;
         this.coins = 0;
    },
};


console.log("lives = " + game.lives);    // should be 3
console.log("coins = " + game.coins);    // should be 0
console.log("points = " + game.points);  // should be 0
game.coins = 0;
console.log("points = " + game.points);  // should be 20
game.playerDies();
console.log("lives = " + game.lives);    // should be 2
game.playerDies();
game.playerDies();
game.playerDies();
console.log("lives = " + game.lives);    // should be 0
game.newGame();
console.log("lives = " + game.lives);    // should be 3
console.log("coins = " + game.coins);    // should be 0
```

Comment: Why do you want the 4th output to be 20? How does that work? Also, what is the function `playerDies` supposed to *return* since your test code never looks at that returned value?

Answer (score 2):

You can put `if` statement in your `playerDies` method

```js
playerDies: function() {
  if (this.lives > 0) {
    return this.lives -= 1
  }

  return 0
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but in order for it to work I had to remove the "return."

Comment: It would be better to return zero instead of `undefined` if there are no lives left!